# Finding the range of variable over which a function is negative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I find the range of variable $x$ (between 0 and 1) such that the value of a certain function is negative?

For example, let $f(x,y,z)=xy+xz-y$. How do I determine the sub-interval of $(0,\,1)$ such that $f(x,y,z) < 0,\ y=2,\ z=1$?

Comment: Check [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

Comment: Surely you don't need *Mathematica* to solve this, because $f(x, 2, 1) = -2+3x$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, Anjan Kumar.

Comment: Murray sir, I used just a small arbitrary example for understanding.

Comment: @DauoodSaleem Are you aware that you can upvote and accept answers if they solve your problem? It's the best way to say thanks to the people who took the time to help you. Check [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.

Comment: Thank you sir, I don't know these things.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x y + x z - y

Reduce[f[x, 2, 1] < 0 && 0 <= x <= 1]
Simplify[f[x, 2, 1] < 0 && 0 <= x <= 1]
Simplify @ Resolve[f[x, 2, 1] < 0 && 0 <= x <= 1]
```

all give

> 0 <= x < 2/3

Answer (score 1):

As suggested:

```
Reduce[x y + x z - y < 0 && 0 < x < 1, x]

(* 
   (y < 0 && z < 0 && y/(y + z) < x < 1) || (y == 0 && z < 0 && 0 < x < 1)
   || (y > 0 && ((z <= 0 && 0 < x < 1) || (z > 0 && 0 < x < y/(y + z)))) 
*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.